# Can't remove magicline from CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

There doesn't seem to be a solution documented just yet, but I have a very annoying problem. I'm using the latest version of CKEditor in my Rails app and I can't get these annoying lines out of it:

[image]

I don't even know what those gray blocks are, indicating that those are hidden fields. I tried to remove the magiclines plugin, but it doesn't seem to be helping:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
        config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
        config.removePlugins = 'magicline,about';
        config.extraPlugins = 'dialogadvtab';
        config.fullPage = true;
        config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [magicline](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/magicline) plguin allows inserting new lines into places where normally it would be very hard e.g. between two tables.

What you can see above is [showborders](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/showborders) plugin which lets you see table outline if the table has no border specified. THat outline is only used inside the editor. You will not see it after you publish editor content somewhere.

If you want to remove it, please use `config.removePlugins = 'showborders';`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know which plugins that show the red line and the hidden field buttons?

Comment: The Hidden Field is part of forms plugin - https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/forms. I have no idea what do you mean by plugin showing the red line?

Comment: It looks like there was another plugin that had been enabled. Think it was "show" something. I also had to disable the "forms" plugin too

Comment: I'm not familiar with any "red line" plugin. All i can recommend is that you go though CKEditor SDK https://sdk.ckeditor.com/ where more or less all functionality is shown. Maybe you will find your plugin there.  You could also go through add-ons repository - https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/plugins/all.

Comment: Sorry. After looking at the config.js file again, it was just the forms plugin in addition to magicline that I had to remove. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. It could be the Magic Line you had in mind as it is being presented by dashed red/orange line with Enter icon at the end.